# How to detect if dynamic web page in WebBrowser redraws?

Tags: windows, delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I'm using TCppWebBrowser, which is a shell around Windows' WebBrowser control, to grab images from web pages. In most cases these will be dynamic pages, e.g. a running clock. If I just loop and call

```
  ViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1, NULL, NULL, FormHDC,
```

this works fine, but it's using more resources than required. E.g. if the clock updates once a second I would only have to call above code once a second.

Is there any way to detect the dynamic page redraws/repaints/refreshes?

Comment: I doubt there is some easy solution to this since TWebBrowser component is just a wrapper for Internet Explorer and thus doesn't expose all functionalities of IE. In order to achieve what you want your would either have to be able to monitor rendering mechanism which isn't expoised through TBweBrowser component or monitor script execution which I'm not sure whether it is possible or not as I have never tried it before with TWebBrowser component.

Comment: @SilverWarior I already access the webbrowser control directly (or I would not be able to grab its contents) so that isn't the problem, the problem is I cannot find anything exposed by this control that tells me it rendered. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter much whether you are using TWebBrowser component that ships with c++builder or accessing IWebBrowser2 interface direcly as both ways provide only limited Access to Internet Explorer functionality. Especially if we are talking about core functionalities like rendering system and such.